# Pubchem compound database into oracle

Tags: pubchem

Did anyone know a way to import easy all the data from the pubchem compound database into an oracle database (11g)?

I didn't find any solution which solves my problem

Comment: Try asking this on http://www.biostars.org/

Comment: thank you. if i have any solution i will post it